# Javascript summing up distinct values in an object

Tags: javascript

```
[{name:"A", value:10}, {name:"A", value:20}, {name:"B", value:15}, {name:"B", value:25}, {name:"C", value:30}]
```

I have an object like above , I want to sum the distinct name. output [A:30, B:40, C:30]. ES6 code preferable.

Comment: What's the specific issue? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own, tell what you've tried to achieve the goal and add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question if possible.

Comment: I am unable to find a solution to this. tried with reduce and map functions

Comment: Including your attempt(s) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object to store the values for each `name`.

```js
let arr = [{name:"A", value:10}, {name:"A", value:20}, {name:"B", value:15}, {name:"B", value:25}, {name:"C", value:30}];
let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  (acc[curr.name] = acc[curr.name] || {name: curr.name, value: 0}).value += curr.value;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks..this works like a charm

Comment: @DineshBeura No problem.